# JavaScript object with public getter and setter methods

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, constructor, prototype

Yesterday, I posted about [prototypal inheritance and constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11662573/confused-about-javascript-prototypal-inheritance-with-constructors). I finally settled on an approach that keeps the code nice and tidy and leaves the prototype alone at the cost of possibly minor performance impact:

```
function Card(value) {
    // setValue is a public instance method
    this.setValue = function (val) {
        if (!range[val]) {
            val = drawRandom();
        }

        // value is a public instance variable
        this.value = val;

        return val;
    };

    this.setValue(value);
}
```

My problem with this approach, however, is that I have to call the setValue method whenever I want to set the value of a Card instance to get the validation. What I'd like to do instead is have a custom setter method. Here's what I have so far:

```
function Card(val) {
    // value is a private instance variable
    var value;

    // This is a private instance method
    // It's also self-invoking, but that's beside the point
    (function (x) {
        if (!range[x]) {
            x = drawRandom();
        }

        value = x;
    }(val));

    this.__defineGetter__("value", function () {
        return value;
    });

    // Some code duplication
    this.__defineSetter__("value", function (x) {
        if (!range[x]) {
            return false;
        }

        value = x;

        return x;
    });
}
```

This works well. Calling `var card = new Card()` gives me an instance with a random value, and calling `card.value = null` fails because it's out of range.

My problem with this, other than the fact that it is obviously much longer, is it seems like I'm duplicating some of the code. It would be nice if the setter method was called along with the constructor. That way, I could eliminate the whole self-invoking private instance method.

Comment: Why not just write `this.value = val;` after defining the setter method? (sorry it took me so many tries to word that comment properly :-)

Comment: `Object.defineProperty` is more widely supported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should always set the `value` with `obj.value = newValue`, even internally, because it invokes your validation.  When in the constructor that means:

```
this.value = val;
```

But that won't work if you do it *before* the setter and getter are declared.  So move it *after* so that the setter function will exist when it's set.

---

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/8tCjm/4/

```
var drawRandom = function () {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
};

var range = {
    1: 'Ace',
    2: 'Two',
    3: 'Three'
};

function Card(val) {
    var value;

    this.__defineGetter__('value', function () {
        return value;
    });

    this.__defineSetter__('value', function (x) {
        if (range[x]) {
            value = x;
        } else {
            value = drawRandom();
        }

        return value;
    });

    this.value = val;
};

console.log(new Card(1).value); // 1
console.log(new Card(2).value); // 2
console.log(new Card(3).value); // 3

console.log(new Card(987).value); // not 987 (1-3)
​
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your suggestion. `this.value` means that value would become a public property and I would not be able to protect it by means of a setter function. Furthermore, I only want the value to be random if the value that is given is not in the range.

Comment: If you call `this.value` from inside the constructor after you create the setter function, the setter function is invoked and used.  `this.value = 123` and `obj.value = 123` do the same thing if `this === obj`.  Though rereading your question you probably want `this.value = value;` instead.  And if that is out of range, the setter will fix it.

Comment: I tried changing `return value` to `return this.value` in my getter and `value = x` to `this.value = x` in my setter and Firefox died: `too much recursion: this.value = x;`

Comment: Updated my answer with a working example.  You got that error because `this.value` invokes the getter function, and if you call that from the getter, obviously it will call itself.  Keep in mind that `var value` and `this.value` are totally unrelated.  They are 2 totally different variables and can be handled independently.  So use `this.value` and `this.value =` everywhere, except the getter/setter where you access the local variable directly.

Comment: x is always null. Do I need to set `x = val`?

Comment: Nope.  In my example, if `x = null`, then `range[x]` means `range[null]` which returns `null`, which is falsy and the `else` clause executes.  And, in my example, any value for `x` that is not 1, 2 or 3 will fail "validation" instead use a value from `drawRandom()`.  Which you can prove by `console.log(new Card().value);` which logs 1, 2 or 3.

Answer (score 2):

Functions are first class objects in Javascript, so you can totally just do something like this to eliminate the duplication:

```
function setter (x) {
    if (!range[x]) {
        return false;
    }
    return x;
}
(function (x) {
    value = setter(x);
    if (!value) {
        value = drawRandom();
    }

}(val));

this.__defineGetter__("value", function () {
    return value;
});

// Some code duplication
this.__defineSetter__("value", setter);
```

Comment: This works very well but ultimately I went with Alex's solution.